# Batch Text Rewriting/Creating

Tags: batch-file, time, overwrite

I don't know if this has been asked before, but I would very much like an answer or a link of a similar question.

I want to make a sort of storage batch file, once you type in an input, say, "English Lit Coursework", it saves it to a txt file. Then the program checks computer time and alerts me a few days before "English Lit Coursework" is due.

Once I finish the assignment, I just delete the "English Lit Coursework" entry, or make code that does that.

My question is, how can I get user input to rewrite/create (if not available)  a .txt file, then read it?

Comment: I have edited your question. I assume this is for assignment tracking, is that correct? How do you want to specify the due date for assignments? Also, if you have tried anything, sample code will get you better answers.

Comment: You can use the `>` (write) and `>>` (append) operators, to write text to a file. For example - `echo Some text > file.txt`

Comment: Well, you could do this - as an exercise. Date-manipulation in batch isn't for the faint-of-heart though. Personally, I'd just google "Stickies".

Comment: I would really like for you to be able to view, add and delete all entries. I tried the echo whatever > file.txt, but i'd really like for USER INPUT to go into the txt, not just programmed text.

Comment: The free `ReminderFox` add-on runs under `Firefox` that can help you track dates, tasks, and times.  This is not a good task for a batch file.

Comment: All right, I'll try something a bit simpler, thanks anyway guys.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for the part about saving user input to a text file, just simply type `echo name of text file > text_file.txt` that will obviously store it to a text document. If you want the user to type what it wants you to type (ex: Please enter your Username.) then you would type:

```
:: some code here
set /p input = Please enter your Username.
echo %input% > username.txt
:: rest of code here
```

Where `input` is the variable assigned to whatever it will say in the text document. Say if I typed "bob" in the part that will ask for my username, it will save "bob" to `username.txt`

I hope this helped any :)

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
@echo off
set /p name=Assignment name: 
set /p due=Due date: 
copy /y nul assignment.bat
(
    echo set name=%name%
    echo set due=%due%
)>assignment.bat
:loop
if /i "%due%" NEQ "%date%" (
    call assignment.bat
    goto loop
)
echo %name% is due!
pause >nul
```

This basically asks you to input the name and due date of the assignment, creates a new batch file "assignment.bat" and puts in commands to set the name and due date, then calls that batch file until it is the due date, when it will say that the assignment is due. When you enter the date, you will need to enter the first three letters of the day of the week, then the numbers for the date, for example: Thu 04/17/2014
If you want it to alert you before the due date, just enter the date you want it to alert you. Keep in mind that you will have to keep the batch file running in the background. You can start it by using start /min and manually editing assignment.bat so that the batch file runs minimized and won't be a problem. I hope this solves your problem!